# Synopsys VCS message severity change from warning to error

Tags: verilog, synopsys-vcs

I want to change the severity of a VCS message from warning to error.

E.g.:

```
Warning-[TMR] Text macro redefined
```

I want to change TMR to Error severity instead of warning.

Please suggest me a way of doing this. Where am I supposed to do this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the next flag to your VCS command:
 -error="TMR"